# Wrong city name correction for Kyiv

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Official latin name is Kyiv, but careers changes it to Kiev, which is wrong.
http://www.uazone.net/Kiev_Kyiv.html

Comment: I think it's **Kiev or Kyiv** as stated by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiev). Both can be used.

Comment: Salomonic compromise: use the Finnish `Kiova`, making everyone equally unhappy.

Comment: @j0k Sorry, but wikipedia is not always right :) And I posted link where you can read official statement. So this is clearly a bug.

Comment: We also spell Deutschland "Germany".  Where do we stop trying to be pedantic and just try to *get the message across*?  Every English speaker who's heard of Kiev has seen it spelled that way.

Comment: As someone who is sick and tired of seeing Beijing called Peking and other incorrect romanizations, (especially true in some languages), I can relate.

Comment: We are somewhat at the mercy of out geocoding provider, which is Yahoo. Here is the [query](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22kyiv%22&format=json&callback=).

I’ve asked them to update it in their [forums](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/Kiev-is-now-officially-Kyiv-geo-places-/1350322043930-172ca8e5-88db-40d6-b636-2a7fd0aeb7d4). Will follow up when there is news.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ of course Peking is wrong, it should be Pekking - in the name of Pekka!

Comment: ... making me the Emperor of China? I like that.

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo appears to have [responded](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/Kiev-is-now-officially-Kyiv-geo-places-/1350322043930-172ca8e5-88db-40d6-b636-2a7fd0aeb7d4), and the query [looks good](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22kiev%22&format=json&callback=).

Unfortunately, we don't have [many jobs](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=kiev&range=100&distanceUnits=Miles) listed there! What employers in Ukraine should our salespeople be calling? :)