# Unable to enter city on careers

Tags: bug, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does careers location field change Jyväskylä to Jyvaskyla?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28080/why-does-careers-location-field-change-jyvaskyla-to-jyvaskyla)
>   [Wrong city name correction for Kyiv](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151435/wrong-city-name-correction-for-kyiv)

When I enter the city where I live (which is [Tivat, Montenegro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tivat)), the city name is being "auto-corrected" using the name deprecated by 220+ years (1420 to 1797), to "Teodo".

There's no option to disable the broken auto-correction.

Comment: Unhelpful "feature", that.

Comment: Pfft, just because they issued a deprecation notice back in 1797, unless they've actually *removed* it from the public API, it's still totally kosher to use... right?

Comment: Well, even your Wikipedia link states that the name is still Teodo in Italian and Venetian, from where probably was borrowed in English.

Comment: @Adinia, I linked to the English wikipedia. As you can see, in English it's called "Tivat" not "Teodo". I never lived in Italy or Venice, and I'm sure all my systems preferences say "U.S. English". If the web site uses Italian language for geographic names, this behavior is a bug.

Comment: I just pointing that the 'Teodo' name is not completely deprecated today, as one might get the impression from your question; as for your question, see this related post (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36646/154375)

Comment: @Adinia, it is completely deprecated today. In both English and Montenegrin languages it's called "Tivat".